# How to generate Label debug info in GreenHills assembler?

Tags: assembly, embedded, gnu, gnu-assembler, greenhills

I'd like to generate debug info for labels in assembly files assembled by GreenHills assembler so that it is visible to debuggres

in GAS "GNU Assembler" it is done like that:

```
.func FuncName [,Lablel]


.endfunc
```

but his generates error in GreenHills Assembler

is there an Equivalent?

Comment: There should be documentation with the assembler. As that is a commercial (and not cheap) product, you should ask Greenhills.